# when dividing two integer result truncated to 0

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, embedded

when i divide two integer and if the result is below like 0.987, then it become zero

```
uint8_t time = 11;
volatile uint8_t val[2] = {11,12};

return  (uint8_t) (time* (val[0] / val[1]))     // 11 * (11/12)
```

from above code the return value is 0, (i.e 11/12 = 0.916 ,but becomes zero),
any other way to make return value to 11, that is 11/12 to 1 not 0 ?

Comment: One option is to use floats, the other is to use fixed point arithmetic. So essentially, multiply everything by some large number e.g. 1000 or however many decimal points you require and remember where the decimal point should be.

Comment: Why are you dividing before you perform the multiplication?

Comment: See also [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021853/dividing-integers-in-c-rounds-the-value-down-gives-zero-as-a-result)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pure software question and not electronic design.

Comment: Basically, you need to study basic integer arithmetic in some C programming book. There's no such thing as the compiler reading the programmer's mind and then doing an implicit conversion to floating point.

Comment: Generally, floating point should be avoided like the plague on AVR, since it doesn't have a FPU. So if one finds themselves needing floating point on an AVR, they are either confused or they picked the wrong MCU for the task. Fixed point arithmetic with integers works just fine in most cases, simply multiply before dividing. Floating point is only needed when you wish to do advanced math with math.h, such as geometry/trigonometry, AI/fuzzy logic programming etc. In which case AVR is definitely the wrong choise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line

```
return  (uint8_t) (time* (val[0] / val[1]))     // 11 * (11/12)
```

the integer expression (val[0]/val[1]), which is computed first due to the parentheses,  returns zero, and anything multiplied by zero is also zero.

If you changed that line slightly to read

```
return  (uint8_t) ((time* val[0]) / val[1])     // (11*11)/12)
```

you would get the answer 10, which is very close to the true value of 121/12.

The normal rules for integer division in C is to truncate, to round down towards -ve infinity. If you want to stick with integer division, then you can make rounding happen if you code it explicitly, by adding half your denominator to your numerator before division.

If you have the code space and execution time, you could use floats, for getting numbers that you recognise without having to be concerned with calculation order and truncation.

A halfway house is to use fixed point integer arithmetic, if you have the RAM space for longer variables. Work in a large base like 1000 (for convenient display of fractions) or 65536 (for convenient slicing of numbers into integer and fractional parts), and use unit16 or uint32s.

Answer (score 2):

Integer division `M/N` in C always rounds down, like `floor(M/N)` would do for floats. A common way to implement different rounding rules is:

- `(M+N/2)/N` for balanced rounding
- `(M+N-1)/N` for rounding up